# Importing an existing maven Project into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven-2

I have an existing Maven Project with me .
I am using Eclipse Helios as my IDE , i need to import an existing maven Project into my IDE .

Please tell me what is the correct approach to import an exisiting maven Application ??
(Should we choose Import Existing maven Project option or 
Should we choose import  Exisiting Projects into Workspace option ??

Please let me know , thank you very much .

Answer (score 11):

Use **Import->Maven->Existing Maven Projects**

I'm assuming, you've m2eclipse plugin installed in your Eclipse.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use mvn plugin "eclipse:eclipse" for setting up the parameters for eclipse
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/myeclipse-mojo.html

After which you can choose, "create from existing source" under "create new project"

Answer (score 0):

Include the m2e plugin into eclipse
Windows >> Install new software
enter this site to download the m2e plugin
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases